# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pip

I would like to connect to Oracle database from VS Code. In the Terminal I ran

```
pip install cx_oracle
```

and it stated:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cx_oracle in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (8.1.0)
```

but when I ran the code: `import cx_Oracle` it returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1e79d9171cfb> in <module>

----> 6 import cx_Oracle

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

In Extensions in VS Code I entered `cx_Oracle` in the search bar and it showed `No extensions found`.

How to use 'cx_Oracle' in VS Code?

---

Update:

Changed the interpreter to python38 as seen in screenshot below but didn't seem to work.
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with VSCode extensions; this is a python error. Sounds like you need to change the interpreter to C:\python38 . You should also verify in the CMD that you can do the import

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, thanks for the reply. Could you please tell me how I could do it?

Comment: Refer docs on [Selecting an Environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried to change the interpreter but nothing changed. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Seems okay to me. Maybe restart VSCode

Comment: Yeah I did but nothing happened @OneCricketeer

Comment: And if you run the python.exe under `c:\python38` and do the import, do you get the same error?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, how can I do that? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Open the start menu, find and run Python. Should open a terminal prompt where you can try to do the import. Or you  might have IDLE installed and can try the same there. If those work, then the problem is indeed VSCode

Comment: There was no error. Does that mean problem lies with vs code? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Review where you can 'change the interpreter'.  For me with VS Code with the Python extension, there is a preference 'Python PATH' that contains the Python executable to use.  You need to make sure this executable has cx_Oracle installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download the whl file of cx-Oracle from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/bb/e49a283467ba4f0b9abcefafd2b9e98cb81b1778e9d97f898e8fabdab370/cx_Oracle-8.1.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl).

For example download the file to `F:/file`.

Then use command `pip install F:/file/cx_Oracle-8.1.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` to install.

Comment: I don't recommend that.  There doesn't appear to be an issue with pip downloading the official cx_Oracle package from PyPI, so there should be no reason to do a manual download.  The key is to make sure the correct pip is invoked.